# In Ruby, should I use ||= or if defined? for memoization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memoization

Should I use `if defined?`

```
 return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
 @current_user_session = UserSession.find
```

Or `||=`

```
@current_user_session ||= UserSession.find
```

I noticed the `if defined?` method being used more and more recently.  Is there any advantage to one over the other?  Personally, I prefer `||=` for readability. I also think Rails might have a `memoize` macro which provides this behavior transparently.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Be careful: x ||= y assigns x = y if x returns false. That may mean that x is undefined, nil, or false.

There are many times variables will be defined and false, though perhaps not in the context of the @current_user_session instance variable.

If you desire conciseness, try the conditional construct:

```
defined?(@current_user_session) ?
    @current_user_session : @current_user_session = UserSession.find
```

or just:

```
defined?(@current_user_session) || @current_user_session = UserSession.find
```

if you just need to initialize the variable.

Comment: Do you mean `defined?(@current_user_session) or @current_user_session = UserSession.find` (`or` instead of `||`)?

Answer (score 1):

Rails does have memoization, check out the screencast below for a great introduction:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/137-memoization

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable

  belongs_to :category

  def filesize(num = 1)
    # some expensive operation
    sleep 2
    12345789 * num
  end

  memoize :filesize
end
```

Comment: However, do NOT use Rails' memoization if any of your parameters are Hashes unless you're on Ruby 1.9.

Comment: `ActiveSupport::Memoizable` was deprecated in Rails 3.2.

Comment: @BobAman I'm on Ruby 1.9 but I still have issues when I use memoization with hash params. I'm also on rails 3.0

Comment: @sjobe Yeah, basically you just shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the nicer `||=` produces a warning (on 1.8.6 and 1.8.7, at least) about uninitialized instance variables, while the more verbose `defined?` version does not.

On the other hand, this probably does what you want:

```
def initialize
  @foo = nil
end

def foo
  @foo ||= some_long_calculation_for_a_foo
end
```

But this almost certainly does not:

```
def initialize
  @foo = nil
end

def foo
  return @foo if defined?(@foo)
  @foo = some_long_calculation_for_a_foo
end
```

since `@foo` will *always* be defined at that point.

Comment: the whole point of defined? is to check for uninitialized instance variables.

Comment: Also, defined?(:@foo) ALWAYS returns "expression".  You meant defined?(@foo).  defined?(@foo) returns either nil or "instance-variable".

Comment: @Dinesh Your question doesn't really make sense, but I suppose it's possible the answer you're looking for is the REPL – just type it into `irb`.