# How do you initialize variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, initialization, memoization

Are there any differences between the following ways of initialization of variables?

```
@var ||= []
@var = [] if @var.nil?
@var = @var || []
```

Please share your way initializing a variable and state the pros & cons.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963868/in-ruby-should-i-use-or-if-defined-for-memoization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@var ||= []` and `@var = @var || []` are equal it will set `var` to `[]` if it's `false` or `nil`

`@var = [] if @var.nil?` is more specific - will re-set `var` to `[]` only if it's equal to `nil`

Comment: So will rails automatically checks `@var` is null in the `||` case? or will `.nil?` a small small overhead?

Comment: Yes, all these examples checks for `nil`. 1st and 3rd also checks for `false`

Answer (score 5):

If you have warnings on (and you should!), `@var ||= []` behaves differently to `@var = @var || []`:

```
irb(main):001:0> $VERBOSE = true
=> true
irb(main):002:0> @var ||= []
=> []
irb(main):003:0> @var2 = @var2 || []
(irb):3: warning: instance variable @var2 not initialized
=> []
irb(main):004:0>
```

If you wish to check whether `@var` is defined or not, and you're happy if it's `nil` or `false`, you can use

```
@var = [] unless defined?(@var)
```

This won't work with local variables though, as noted in [In Ruby why won't `foo = true unless defined?(foo)` make the assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291646/in-ruby-why-wont-foo-true-unless-definedfoo-make-the-assignment)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed the warning message before. BTW, how to show the warning messages in the console? Mine didn't show it.

Comment: If you're using version 1.9.2, `irb -w` or `irb -d` will turn on the warnings (I don't know whether the similar `irb -v` will work). For earlier versions, you have to set `$VERBOSE` yourself. (`irb -d` working was the result of [my bugfix](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3634) that resulted from another person's SO question)