# What are the drawbacks of using ||= syntax to perform memoization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memoization

I have noticed several individuals comment on how their use of `||=` to perform [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization) was 'sloppy' but they did it anyway 'because they were in a rush'.

I also found [ActiveSupport::Memoizable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Memoizable/InstanceMethods.html).

I'm lead to conclude that `||=` has drawbacks.

So what are they?

Comment: Hmm. The answer to this appears to be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963868/in-ruby-should-i-use-or-if-defined-for-memoization but it's a different question. Does that make it a duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the biggest reason I'm aware of is that you can't memoize `nil` or `false` values like that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading this:
[When to use memoization in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696338/when-to-use-memoization-in-ruby-on-rails)

And this:
http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/09/20/a-guide-to-memoization/